# How to define a preprocessor macro based on symbol presence with CMake?

Tags: cmake

This works:

```
check_symbol_exists(strsep "string.h" HAVE_STRSEP)
if(NOT HAVE_STRSEP)
    add_compile_definitions(NO_STRSEP=1)
endif()
```

But it's also quite verbose, especially once more get added. Is there a better/shorter/more idiomatic way to do this?

(I'm using those definitions to conditionally include drop-in replacements for missing functions.)

Comment: Not sure what kind of more "idiomatic way" you expect. If you need **many** preprocessor macros to be defined in such way, then you could write a function which will be called like `add_compile_definitions_if_symbol_is_absent(strsep "string.h" HAVE_SRTSEP NO_STRSEP=1)`. Inside that function you could call `check_symbol_exists` and `add_compile_definitions` with proper parameters.

Comment: You could also create a `config.h.cmake` template file that stores the results of the system introspection and include the file in your source files. A typical line in this template file is `#cmakedefine HAVE_STRSEP` or `#cmakedefine01 HAVE_STRSEP`. See [configure_file docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html)  for further information

Comment: Don't use directory commands like `add_compile_definitions`. Use the `target_*` functions or `configure_file` instead.